# Passportjs redirect adds hashtag in the URL

Tags: url, angular-ui-router, passport.js, hashtag, html5mode

I have a login page on my mean-stack website. The website uses `html5mode`, and has `<base href="/1/" />`. The login uses `Passport.js`, eg:

```
router.get('/' + process.env.versionNumber + '/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'] }));
router.get('/' + process.env.versionNumber + '/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', {
        successRedirect: '/' + process.env.versionNumber + '/dashboard',
        failureRedirect : '/' + process.env.versionNumber + '/login',
        failureFlash : true
    }))
```

For Twitter, GitHub and Linkedin, it all redirects to `https://localhost:3000/1/dashboard`. However, Google redirects to `https://localhost:3000/1/dashboard#` and Facebook redirects to `https://localhost:3000/1/dashboard#_=_`.

Does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: I don't think this is exclusive to angular.  I am using it without angular and am having the same issue.  the successRedirect value in my callback url is where I point to dashboard.html.  The # only started showing up after I implemented passport with the passport-google-oauth20 strategy